# How can I use ArrayList remove in loop java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

If a value of an object in scoreArray is smaller than any other objects in scoreArray, I want to remove that value. However I have no idea how can I remove ArrayList object in loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> scoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int k = 0; k < people ; k++) {
            int compare = scoreArray.get(k);


            for (int j = 0; j < people; j++) {
                if(compare < scoreArray.get(j)){

                    //scoreArray.remove(k);

                    }
                } 

            }
```

Comment: So you want to remove the smallest value?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Javadoc for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  I would suggest starting there.

Comment: `scoreArray.remove(Collections.min(scoreArray));`

Comment: @4castle Oo! Your answer was beautiful. Will it remove **all** copies of the smallest value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the smallest 2 elements in an arraylist in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883788/removing-the-smallest-2-elements-in-an-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: @finnrayment My answer just removes one copy. janos shows how to adapt it to remove all copies.

Comment: @4castle Ahah, as I have noticed! Lovely either way!

Answer (score 5):

Find the minimum element and then remove all occurrences:

```
int min = scoreArray.stream().min(Integer::compare).orElse(0);
scoreArray.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(min));
```

This solution is safer than the even more compact `scoreArray.removeAll(Collections.min(scoreArray))`,
because this will not throw `NoSuchElementException` when `scoreArray` is empty.

If you want to remove only the first occurrence of the minimal value,
then write like this:

```
if (!scoreArray.isEmpty()) {
  scoreArray.remove(scoreArray.stream().min(Integer::compare).get());
  // alternatively: scoreArray.remove(Collections.min(scoreArray));
}
```

Comment: `Collections.min(scoreArray)` is a bit simpler.

Comment: @4castle `Collections.min(scoreArray)` is simpler but less save, because it will throw `NoSuchElementException` if `scoreArray` is empty. But it's a good thing to mention, added to my answer.

Comment: @janos It depends on what you define as "less safe." If the list shouldn't be empty, then an exception would be appropriate.

Comment: @4castle if solution A works when an extra condition X is satisfied, and solution B works *always* without further knowledge, I think that means that solution B is more safe. The fewer conditions you have for the correctness of your code, the less mental burden, the less room for mistakes. `Collections.min` should probably have been designed to return `Optional<T>` instead of throwing.

Comment: I want to get one element from scoreArray, and compare it with other elements in scoreArray.
And if only once, this element is smaller than other one, I want to remove it. 
This code can solve this problem? I have no idea where can I put this code in mine. Can you give me some more help please?

Comment: @sujin what would you like to do if there are multiple elements that are minimal? For example in `1,2,1` the minimum is 1, but it appears twice. If you want to remove both of them, then this code will solve your problem. I amended my answer with an alternative if you want to remove only the first occurrence. As for where to put this code, replace your `for` loop with this code.

Comment: @janos I understood. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to simply remove the smallest value. This only requires a single for-loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> scoreArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Integer smallestValue;
for (Integer i : scoreArray) {
    smallestValue = (smallestValue == null || smallestValue < i) ? i : smallestValue;
}

scoreArray.removeAll(Collections.singleton(smallestValue));
```

**Edit:**

I'm no good with the Java 8 streams, but if you are using Java 8+, then use the other answer provided by @Janos. Much better and elegant.

Comment: No, I want to get one element from scoreArray, and compare it with other elements in scoreArray.
And if only once, this element is smaller than other one, I want to remove it. So, there will be more than one value that should be removed. But thank you for your help :)

Comment: @sujin I'm sorry I don't understand what your asking. My code does exactly that?